# check duplicates value and input value with python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, count, duplicates, openpyxl

I want to check duplicates value and input value in excel file. The content of excel file is changed everyday, so I don't know which row is the last row.

The image of the excel file is the output that I want to do. The image is as followed. enter image description here

[image]

In the excel file image, if the value of 'B' cell is duplicates, shiping cost should be input '3,000' one time, otherwise input '3,000'

This is the code that I have done. In this case, every column of [Q5:Q max row] are all '3,000' If you have any idea, please let me know that.

```
wb = load_workbook(merged_excel_file)
ws = wb.active

last_row = ws.max_row

for o in range(5, last_row+1):
Name_file = ws.cell(row=o, column=2).value

if Name_file.count(ws.cell(row=o, column=2).value) == 1:
    ws.cell(row=o, column=17).value = '3000'

else:
    continue
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do. Is it that for any value in Column 2 that is *not* a duplicate, you will write '3,000' to Column 17 in that same row? 

Right now, for each o, you are providing a value for Name_file, then checking whether the same single cell has the same value (it does, you haven't changed anything, including the value of o - there isn't a second loop), and then inputs '3000' into Column 17 for every row by definition.

Comment: I solved the problem as followed.

    for o in range(5, last_row + 1):
        ws.cell(row=o, column=17).value = f"=if(countif($B$5:B{o},B{o}) = 1,3000,"'0'")"

Comment: I thought it has been solved but the excel file only showed excel formula, not the cell value. I am a biginner of python, so I didn't understand how to make second loop. Can you show me the example to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid multiple loops over the same cells, which is comparatively slow, you could store their values in an array.

```
wb = load_workbook(merged_excel_file)
ws = wb.active

last_row = ws.max_row
names = []
for o in range(5, last_row+1):
    names.append(ws.cell(row=o, column=2).value)
```

Then, you can loop over each value in the array using `enumerate()`, which again just requires accessing the array from memory rather than looping over the cells again:

```
for o, name in names:
    if names.count(name) == 1:
        ws.cell(row = o, column = 17).value = 3_000
```

Since you're dealing with a number, I've changed the cell to write an integer rather than a string (the underscore doesn't do anything, it's just a visual separator like when you write "3,000").

Note: Python ends if loops automatically based on indentation, so you don't need an `else: continue` statement! Do watch out for the indentation though. If something's inside a loop, like your `for` loop above, it should be indented one tab more than the `for` statement. That includes your `Name_file` assignment, and the `if` statement.

This should work for now. If you want to start doing more advanced things with data tables, pandas is the gold standard library to learn more about.